# Codeigniter if data inserted return true to json again ? it's possible?

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I'm using json to post data to controller but i can't do some effects if data is inserted to database successfully,

This if statement does not work in this javascript code ?
I mean .like-btn .html() does not work but data inserted in database ?

> My experience in Javascript between 0 and 10 :D
>
> Using Codeigniter 3.0.3

Here's my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".like-btn").click(function(event) {
    var liker_id = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('id'); ?>";
    var post_id = $(this).attr('post-id');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('home/AddLike'); ?>",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {liker_id: liker_id, post_id: post_id},
            success: function(res) {
            if (res)
               {
                  $('.like-btn[post-id = '+post_id+']').html('<span class="fa fa-check"></span> Liked');
               }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's my controller

```
function AddLike() {
    $this->load->helper('string');
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $this->users_model->Add_like();
}
```

And here's my model method

```
function Add_like() {
        
        $this->db->where('liker_id', $this->input->post('liker_id'));
        $this->db->where('post_id', $this->input->post('post_id'));
        $query = $this->db->get('likes_table');     
        if($query->num_rows() == 0) {
            $data = array(
                'liker_id'              => $this->input->post('liker_id'),
                'post_id'               => $this->input->post('post_id')
            );
            $this->db->insert('likes_table', $data);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the output of `res` in javascript? use console.log() to see the result.

Comment: You're not returning any value from your `function AddLike()` you need to pass it something like as `$result = $this->users_model->Add_like(); echo $result ?: false; exit; `

Comment: @DS9 res is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change below on your model:

change `return` to `echo`

```
function Add_like() {

    $this->db->where('liker_id', $this->input->post('liker_id'));
    $this->db->where('post_id', $this->input->post('post_id'));
    $query = $this->db->get('likes_table');     
    if($query->num_rows() == 0) {
        $data = array(
            'liker_id'              => $this->input->post('liker_id'),
            'post_id'               => $this->input->post('post_id')
        );
        $this->db->insert('likes_table', $data);
        echo true;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes u get it but not in model i change it in model does not work but when i change return true; to echo true; in controller works thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should debug your code of ajax response. And you should check whether you are getting any response in **res** variable.

**Important**

 1)In if condition you should use double quotes("") to wrap variable **post_id** like 
    **$('.like-btn[post-id = "'+post_id+'"]').html...**

 2) Another thing is you should return **"true"** as string not as boolean and check with string in ajax success block.

Answer (score 1):

Solved add this line at the end of controller method

```
echo true;
```

code after edit

```
function AddLike() {

    $this->load->helper('string');
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $this->users_model->Add_like();
    echo true;

}
```